# Allow 'table-responsive' (scroll) class to still work for a fixed element

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular 6 to build a table. Currently, the head of the table is set to remain fixed to the top of the page if the user scrolls past it. However, upon applying my 'sticky' class, which has that header fixed to the top, I seem to lose the functionality of the bootstrap 'table-responsive' and can no longer scroll horizontally. How can I keep that enabled so that the header will be fixed vertically to the top, but still scroll horizontally with the rest of the table?

my 'sticky' css class:

```
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 12;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:92%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right:20px!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow-bottom:0px 1px 6px grey;
    -moz-box-shadow-bottom:0px 1px 6px grey;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #cccccc;    
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

(upon applying the items at the end of the sticky class, I can get the table head to scroll still, but it wont be attached to the rest of the table below it)

**My html:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="tabletop" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr #stickyMenu [class.sticky]="sticky">
                <th scope="col" id="th0">Monitoring Point</th>
                <th scope="col" id="th1">Network Health<br><small id="more_detail">(Click icon to see more detail)</small>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" id="th2">Active Alerts</th>
                <th scope="col" id="th3">Velocity (ft/s)</th>
                <th scope="col" id="th4">Water Temperature (°F)</th>
                <th scope="col" id="th5">Depth Readings (in)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="table-responsive"> -->
        <table id="tablebottom" class="table">
            <tbody >
                <tr *ngFor="let item of monitoring_points">
                    <app-sensor-summary [mp]="item"></app-sensor-summary>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my component, I user this to determine where the scroll is in relation to the window, and apply the class when the user scrolls past it:

```
@ViewChild("stickyMenu", {read: ElementRef}) tr: ElementRef;


ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.elementPosition = this.tr.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  handleScroll(elementPosition) {
    this.sticky = (window.pageYOffset >= this.elementPosition);
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `position:sticky;` instead fixed. so it remains in the flow. for older browsers, you may use a polyfill if you need any

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it won't remain fixed to the top

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/byQVdo that's what i talk about. What browser do you use ?

Comment: I see... that one isn't sticking either so that would make sense. I'm in Chrome v74.0.3729.169. Would that be old enough? And what's a good way to get started with a polyfill? thanks